# The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, web-crawler

I am using this code which give me issue

```
       WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("url");
       StreamReader sr =new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        string strLine;
        // Read the stream a line at a time and place each one into the stringbuilder
        while ((strLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // Ignore blank lines
            if (strLine.Length > 0) sb.Append(strLine);
        }
        sr.Close();
       lbl.Text= sb.ToString();
```

i am getting this error

```
The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable
```

Comment: Are you sure the "url" server is up and running?

Comment: yes when i run the url in browser it works fine

Comment: OK, instead of passing the string, try using uri and put everything in try block, you might get an exception if there is any problem related to the uri you're trying to connect to. ref : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aa3d588.aspx

Comment: again same issue..i tried uri also

Answer (score 1):

WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com"); StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

```
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    string strLine;
    // Read the stream a line at a time and place each one into the stringbuilder
    while ((strLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Ignore blank lines
        if (strLine.Length > 0) sb.Append(strLine);
    }
    sr.Close();
```

This Piece of code works just Fine. I replaced online URI from WebRequest.Create("url") method with  WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com"). Please check that part if you are passing the right url.

Comment: Please check this post , It desribes the reasons for 503 error. If your teh server you are trying to access has any of the mentioned problems.http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/503error.htm

Comment: you did not changed anything...my code is also working for some sites but do not work for all sites...